# Spring MVC with JAXB, List response based on a Generic class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jaxb, spring-4, spring-oxm

I am working with Spring 4, together with Spring MVC.

I have the following POJO class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="person")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id",...})
public class Person implements Serializable {

    …

    @Id
    @XmlElement
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    …
}
```

If I want return a list of **Person** through Spring MVC in XML format, I have the following handler

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getxmlpersons/generic", 
        method=RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public JaxbGenericList<Person> getXMLPersonsGeneric(){
    logger.info("getXMLPersonsGeneric - getxmlpersonsgeneric");
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(...);
    …more

    JaxbGenericList<Person> jaxbGenericList = new JaxbGenericList<>(persons);

    return jaxbGenericList;
}
```

Where JaxbGenericList is (**class declaration based on Generics**)

```
@XmlRootElement(name="list")
public class JaxbGenericList<T> {

    private List<T> list;

    public JaxbGenericList(){}

    public JaxbGenericList(List<T> list){
        this.list=list;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    public List<T> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

When I execute the URL, I get the following error stack trace

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not marshal [com.manuel.jordan.jaxb.support.JaxbGenericList@31f8809e]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class com.manuel.jordan.domain.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.manuel.jordan.domain.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
```

**But** If I have this (class declaration not based on Generics):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="list")
public class JaxbPersonList {

    private List<Person> list;

    public JaxbPersonList(){}

    public JaxbPersonList(List<Person> list){
        this.list=list;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    public List<Person> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

and other **handler** method of course, as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getxmlpersons/specific", 
        method=RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public JaxbPersonList getXMLPersons(){
    logger.info("getXMLPersonsSpecific - getxmlpersonsspecific");
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(...);
    …more 

    JaxbPersonList jaxbPersonList = new JaxbPersonList(persons);

    return jaxbPersonList;
}
```

All work fine:

Question, what extra configuration I need to work in peace with only **JaxbGenericList**

**Addition One**

I did not configure a `marshaller` bean, so I think Spring behind the scenes has provided one. Now according with your reply I have added the following:

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(JaxbGenericList.class, Person.class);
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(props);
    return marshaller;
}
```

Something seems missing because I receive 'again':

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not marshal [com.manuel.jordan.jaxb.support.JaxbGenericList@6f763e89]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class com.manuel.jordan.domain.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.manuel.jordan.domain.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
```

Have you tried in a Web Environment? Seems I need tell Spring MVC use that `marshaller`, I said **seems** because other URL working with **not** collections of POJO/XML works fine yet.

I am working with Spring 4.0.5 and Web environment is configured through Java Config

**Addition Two**

Your latest edition suggestion works

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(marshallingMessageConverter());
}

@Bean
public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
    MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setMarshaller(jaxbMarshaller());
    converter.setUnmarshaller(jaxbMarshaller());
    return converter;
}
```

But now my XML not generic and JSON code fails.

For my other XML URL
`http://localhost:8080/spring-utility/person/getxmlpersons/specific`

```
HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

It has been fixed adding or updating:

from:

```
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(JaxbGenericList.class, Person.class);
```

to:

```
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(JaxbGenericList.class, Person.class, JaxbPersonList.class);
```

But for JSON, other URL `http://localhost:8080/spring-utility/person/getjsonperson` again

```
HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

Seems I need add a converter for JSON (I did not define before), I have used the Spring defaults, could you give me a hand please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way this can happen in Spring is if you don't have the marshaller configured properly. Take for example this standalone:

TestApplication:

```
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AbstractApplicationContext context
                = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = context.getBean(Marshaller.class);
        GenericWrapper<Person> personListWrapper = new GenericWrapper<>();
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(1);
        personListWrapper.getItems().add(person);
        marshaller.marshal(personListWrapper, new StreamResult(System.out) );
        context.close();
    }
}
```

AppConfig (notice the `setClassesToBeBound`)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(GenericWrapper.class);
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(props);
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

Domain

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {

    protected Integer id;

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
}
@XmlRootElement
public class GenericWrapper<T> {

    protected List<T> items;

    public GenericWrapper() {}
    public GenericWrapper(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<T> getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            items = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Result running the above application, it'll fail to marshal, with the same cause of the exception

> `Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.stackoverflow.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.`

The cause, if you look at the `AppConfig`, is the method `setClassesToBeBound`. It only includes the `GenericWrapper` class. So why is this a problem?

Let's look at JAXB under the hood:

We interact with JAXB through the `JAXBContext`. Normally it's alright to just create the context with the top level element like

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(GenericWrapper.class);
```

JAXB will pull into the context all classes associated with the class. That's why `List<Person>` works. `Person.class` is explicitly associated.

But in the case of `GenericWrapper<T>`, the `Person` class is nowhere related to the `GenericWrapper`. But if we explicitly put `Person` class into the context, it'll be found, and we can use the generics.

```
JAXBContext context 
                = JAXBContext.newInstance(GenericWrapper.class, Person.class);
```

That being said, under the hood, `Jaxb2Marshaller` uses this same context. Going back to the `AppConfig`, you can see `marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(GenericWrapper.class);`, which is ultimately the same as the first `JAXBContext` creation above. If we add `Person.class`, then we would have the same configuration as the second `JAXBContext` creation.

```
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(GenericWrapper.class, Person.class);
```

Now run the test application again, and it'll get the desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<genericWrapper>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
    </item>
</genericWrapper>
```

### All that being said...

I don't know how you've set up your configuration of the marshaller, or if the framework has a default set up. But you need to get a hold of the marshaller, and configure it to find the classes in one of three ways:

- `packagesToScan`.
- `contextPath`
- or `classesToBeBound` (like I've done above)

This can be done through Java configuration or xml configuration

---

- **See more at the [Spring-JAXB reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#oxm-jaxb)**

---

### **UPDATE** (using Spring web)

So it seems, in a Spring web environment, if you don't specify the http message converter, Spring will use [`Jaxb2RootElemenHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html) and just use the return type as the root element for the context. Haven't checked what's going on under the hood (in the source), but I would assume that the problem lies somewhere in what I described above, where the `Person.class` is not being pulled into the context.

What you can do is specify your own [`MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.html), in the servlet context. To get it to work (with xml config), this is what I added

```
<annotation-driven>
    <message-converters>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
            <beans:property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
            <beans:property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </message-converters>
</annotation-driven>

<beans:bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <beans:property name="classesToBeBound">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.stackoverflow.jaxb.domain.JaxbGenericList</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.stackoverflow.jaxb.domain.Person</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

You could achieve the same with Java confguration, as seen in the [`@EnableWebMcv`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) API, where you extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and override `configureMessageConverters`, and add the message converter there. Something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            converters.add(marshallingMessageConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setMarshaller(jaxbMarshaller());
        converter.setUnmarshaller(jaxbMarshaller());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean 
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxbMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(JaxbGenericList.class, Person.class);
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(props);
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

Using similar controller method:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/people", 
                    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public JaxbGenericList<Person> getXMLPersonsGeneric() {
        JaxbGenericList<Person> personsList = new JaxbGenericList<Person>();
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.setId(1);
        personsList.getItems().add(person1);
        return personsList;
    }
}
```

We get the result we want

[image]:

Comment: Hello, thank you very much by your detailed explanation, has sense, but: could you check the `Addition One` section? It has been added. Thank You.

Comment: Let me know if you have checked this :-D

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot by your support, it works now. But see my `Addition Two` section. It affects other sections

Comment: You have an errata, update the terms: `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` and `@EnableWebMvc`, SO asks for 6 characters to let me update/edit your post, I only have 2 to fix. I can't edit your post.

Comment: How did you know that `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` is used by default? Thank You.

Comment: I can see in the API, an important hierarchy through the `HttpMessageConverter<T>` interface. It has the classes `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` `Jaxb2CollectionHttpMessageConverter` and  `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`. Observe Jackson for **JSON** and **XML** and JAXB for **Root** and **Collection**. Now your solution uses `Jaxb2Marshaller`, it belong in other hierarchy in the API. Little confuse this situation. If you can add an `explanation` in your answer about this observation, pls do it. Thanks in advance.