# How to validate xml using jaxb?

Tags: java, spring, validation, jaxb

I have spring without spring-boot application.
So, I have spring-configuration and web, business and data - layers.

Application changes xml with out World by xml elements.
If client try to write some xml in application, his xml maps to jaxb model in @RestController method and then computing occours on businessLayer.

I need to validate xml file before I pass it in business-layer, how can I make it.

There is User jaxb model like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "RiskMetric")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@EqualsAndHashCode
class User{
    @XmlElement(name="name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name="surname")
    private String surname;
    @XmlElement(name="age")
    privage int age;
}
```

And there is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController{
    @Autowired
    private UserBusinessService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void add(@RequestBody User user){
        service.add(user);   
    }
}
```

Can jaxb use just xsd for validate input messages(I didn't find)

I found code fragment like this:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(locationOfMySchema); 

Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setSchema(schema);
marshaller.marshal(objectToMarshal, new DefaultHandler());
```

But, how to write interceptor for every entity to use this code fragment?

Comment: Take a look at [Spring MVC with JAXB, List response based on a Generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939629/spring-mvc-with-jaxb-list-response-based-on-a-generic-class), [Spring MVC - set JAXB marshaller property when using @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798952/spring-mvc-set-jaxb-marshaller-property-when-using-responsebody)